# Flagging rows that fulfill two conditions in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a large dataset, with hundreds of variables and hundreds of observations, coming from a clinical trial. Variable V1 is a yes/no variable, indicating some condition. V2 is numeric, and representing a dose. T is a time variable. The dataset is "long" shaped, every subject has few observations, one for each time point. For every subject, I want to create a new yes/no variable (can be in a new dataset), which is **yes** if: V1 is "yes" in at least one time point, OR, V2 is above 0 in at least one time point. How do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share an example data set and things you have tried? Seems like an "if then else" implementation to me at a first glance

Comment: I am not sure how to add tables here, so I'll do it in text format: the variables are ID, V1, V2, V3, ...., Time. V1 is yes/no, V2 is numeric. For every ID, I have 10 up to 10 rows. If V1 is "yes" in any of the 10 rows of a specific ID, or, if V2 is >0 for any of the 10 rows of a specific ID, this ID is "yes", otherwise, this ID is "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
data ds;
set ds;
if V1="yes" or V2>0 then do;
flag="yes;
end;
else do;
flag= "no";
end;
```

summarize the dataset to ID level:

```
proc sql;
create table summary as
select ID, count(flag) as flag_cnt
from ds
where flag="yes"
group by ID;
quit;
```

These are the IDs which satisfy the condition

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the code on the example below to verify.

Here (V1="yes" or V2>0) gives a dummy variable for eauch row. When we sum it we have the number of rows satisfying the condition you mentioned for each ID. 
To have a flag, we compare the sum to 0 and put it between () to create a 0/1 variable that you want to have.

hope it helps !

MK

```
 data have;
        input ID V1 $ V2;
        cards;
        1 yes 0
        1 no 0
        1 no 0
        2 no 0
        2 no 0
        2 no 0
        3 no 1
        3 no 0
        4 yes 0
        4 yes 0
        5 yes 1
        5 no 1
        5 yes 0
        ;
    run;



proc sql;
       select ID
              , (sum((V1="yes")or(V2>0))>0) as new_flag
          from have
              group by ID;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data want (keep=id flag);
flag = 'no ';
do until (last.id);
  set have;
  by id;
  if v1 = 'yes' or v2 > 0 then flag = 'yes';
end;
output;
run;
```